How to configure authentication handler in ASP .NET Core?
I am developing an ASP.NET Core Minimal API, and I'm trying to use the Identity Bearer Scheme for authentication by JWT Tokens. I followed a few tutorials to try and achieve that, but I always get this same error when trying to log a user in using the default login endpoint:

No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Identity.Bearer",...)?

I did a little digging and I am supposed to use the BearerTokenExtensions.AddBearerToken method in my program.cs file to configure the authentication in my app. However I am not sure in what context should I use it in and what arguments should I provide.
This is my full program.cs file. I am not sure what exactly I need to do to fix this issue
using Backend.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add Authentication with the Identity.Bearer (JWT) scheme
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints(); 


var ConnString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WorkoutStore");
builder.Services.AddSqlite<ApplicationDBContext>(ConnString);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapIdentityApi<User>(); // Map default endpoints for Identity with Bearer scheme
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();

My login request:
POST http://localhost:5178/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Email": "John.Doe@gmail.com",
    "Password": "Anything@1!"
}


Please use signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync instead of signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync().
Because signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() can only be used with cookies. That's why we get the error.
When working with IdentityCore and jwt, we should use signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync.
